# Is programming the ATTiny85 possible in 1.5?

Tags: attiny

I upgraded to Arduino 1.5.7 in hopes of using the command line interface for a larger project. However, the old package I was using to program the ATTiny85 chip with the Sparkfun Tiny AVR Programmer no longer works. I'm getting the following error:

```
Third-party platform.txt does not define compiler.path. Please report this to the third-party hardware maintainer.
processing.app.debug.RunnerException
    at processing.app.debug.Compiler.getCommandCompilerCPP(Compiler.java:597)
    at processing.app.debug.Compiler.compileFiles(Compiler.java:275)
    at processing.app.debug.Compiler.compileSketch(Compiler.java:642)
    at processing.app.debug.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:125)
    at processing.app.Sketch.build(Sketch.java:1589)
    at processing.app.Sketch.exportApplet(Sketch.java:1611)
    at processing.app.Sketch.exportApplet(Sketch.java:1597)
    at processing.app.Editor$DefaultExportHandler.run(Editor.java:2397)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at processing.app.helpers.StringReplacer.replaceFromMapping(StringReplacer.java:97)
    at processing.app.helpers.StringReplacer.replaceFromMapping(StringReplacer.java:89)
    at processing.app.helpers.StringReplacer.formatAndSplit(StringReplacer.java:37)
    at processing.app.debug.Compiler.getCommandCompilerCPP(Compiler.java:595)
    ... 8 more
```

Does a package exist that will allow me to program the chip in 1.5.7?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can download a version of arduino-tiny for IDE 1.5.x from [here](https://code.google.com/p/arduino-tiny/).

Comment: Where do I extract it? It contains `tiny/avr/...`. Do I extract `/tiny` to `/hardware/...` or do I extract the `avr` subfolder?

Comment: Never mind, this doesn't work in 1.6.